# Bluetooth device no more detected

Tags: release-loki, bluetooth, intel

Since today, my bluetooth is no more detected by elementaryOS.
I don't know why.
Yesterday it was working.
Windows works well (dual boot).

Now, I can't find my bluetooth device.
I have the Xiaomi Notebook 12.5.

```
COMMAND : sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

COMMAND : hciconfig hci0
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:6 acl:0 sco:0 commands:2 errors:0

COMMAND :  dmesg | grep -i blue
[    5.331592] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    5.331610] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.331614] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.331618] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.331624] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.346236] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    5.346242] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    5.346244] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    5.346245] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    5.346249] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    5.346250] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    5.346286] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    5.346308] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    5.346309] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    7.400010] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[    7.431431] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.431435] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.431440] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   15.396818] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[   17.400750] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[   25.397236] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
```

Can you help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you put whats showing on this: sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service